# Kotlin Toast for a multi quiz

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast

I am a complete novice to Kotlin. I am currently trying to build a multiple question quiz in android studio and I would like to know how do I display a toast stating the answer is correct or incorrect once I click submit. I have started the toast in processSubmitButtonClick() but I'm confused on how to get it to know if I have the right or wrong answer. 
String.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AnswerButton</string>
    <string name="australia_question">What is the capital of Australia?</string>
    <string name="australia_answer_brisbane">Brisbane</string>
    <string name="australia_answer_canberra">Canberra</string>
    <string name="australia_answer_perth">Perth</string>
    <string name="australia_answer_sidney">Sidney</string>
    <string name="hint_button_text">Hint</string>
    <string name="submit_button_text">Submit</string>
    <string name="correct_toast">Correct!</string>
    <string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrect!</string>
</resources>
```

Answer.kt

```
package quiz

import androidx.annotation.StringRes


data class Answer (@StringRes val textResId: Int,
                   val isCorrect: Boolean,
                   var isEnabled: Boolean = true,
                   var isSelected: Boolean = false)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package quiz

import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val defaultButtonColor = "#00a2ff"
    private val selectedButtonColor = "#cb297b"

    // view fields
    private lateinit var questionTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var answerButtonList: List<Button>
    private lateinit var hintButton: Button
    private lateinit var submitButton: Button

    //model fields

   private val answerList = listOf(
        Answer(R.string.australia_answer_brisbane, false),
        Answer(R.string.australia_answer_canberra, true),
        Answer(R.string.australia_answer_perth, false),
        Answer(R.string.australia_answer_sidney, false)
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // initialize views
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question_text_view)
        answerButtonList = listOf(
            findViewById(R.id.answer_0_button),
            findViewById(R.id.answer_1_button),
            findViewById(R.id.answer_2_button),
            findViewById(R.id.answer_3_button)
        )
        hintButton = findViewById(R.id.hint_button)
        submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_button)

        // set question text
        questionTextView.setText(R.string.australia_question)

        // set text in answer button views
        for (index in 0..3) {
            answerButtonList[index].setText(answerList[index].textResId)
        }

        // set text for hint and submit buttons
        hintButton.setText(R.string.hint_button_text)
        submitButton.setText(R.string.submit_button_text)

        // attach listeners to answer buttons
        for((answer, button) in answerList.zip(answerButtonList)){
            button.setOnClickListener {
                processAnswerButtonClick(answer)
            }
        }

        // attach listeners to hint button and submit button
        hintButton.setOnClickListener {
            processHintButtonClick()
        }
        submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            processSubmitButtonClick()    
        }

        refreshView()
    }

    private fun processAnswerButtonClick(answer: Answer) {
        val origIsSelected = answer.isSelected

        // deselect all answers
        for (a in answerList.minus(answer)){
            a.isSelected = false
        }

        // toggle clicked button
        answer.isSelected = !origIsSelected

        // refresh the view
        refreshView()
    }

    private fun processHintButtonClick() {
        // hint the first two incorrect answers (even if one is selected)
        answerList
            .filterNot { e -> e.isCorrect }
            .take(2)
            .forEach { a ->
                a.isEnabled = false
                a.isSelected = false 
           }  

          refreshView()
    }

    private fun checkAnswer(userAnswer: Boolean){
       val correctAnswer = answerList[currentIndex].?

        val message = if (userAnswer == correctAnswer){

            R.string.correct_toast
        } else {
            R.string.incorrect_toast
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show()

    }
private fun processSubmitButtonClick( ) {
    answerList
        .forEach { a ->
            a.isEnabled = true
            a.isSelected = false
        }

    for (answer in answerList) {
        if ((answer.isSelected) && (answer.isCorrect)) {
            checkAnswer(true)
        }
        else {
            checkAnswer(false)
        }

     }
        refreshView()
}



    private fun refreshView() {
           hintButton.isEnabled = true

        for((answer, button) in answerList.zip(answerButtonList)){
            button.isEnabled = answer.isEnabled
            button.isSelected = answer.isSelected

            if (answer.isSelected) {
                setButtonColor(button, selectedButtonColor)
            } else {
                setButtonColor(button, defaultButtonColor)
            }
            if (!answer.isEnabled) {
                button.alpha = .5f
                hintButton.isEnabled = false // hint if any answers are hinted
            }
        }
        hintButton.isEnabled = answerList.all { a -> a.isEnabled  }
    }

    private fun setButtonColor(button: Button, colorString: String) {
        button.backgroundTintList =
            ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(colorString))
        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        button.alpha = 1f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your `processSubmitButtonClick()` I think there are two things wrong.

At first you loop through the answers and put all on `isSelected = false`. You won't have a way to tell what answer the user selected after this!

Then you loop again and are trying to show a Toast for every answer there exists, you don't want that.

You might want to do something like this:

```
var correct = false
for (answer in answerList) {
    if (answer.isSelected && answer.isCorrect) {
        correct = true
        break
    }
}

if (correct) {
    //show correct toast
} else {
    //show incorrect toast
}
```